# Create ParseUser from logged user in php

Tags: php, parse-server

I'm having problems when I've tried to create new ParseUsers from a logged user using ParseUser.
I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Tried to
>   save a batch with a cycle.' in
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php:1019

```
            session_start();
            ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );
            $user=new ParseUser();
            $user->set("username",$user);
            $user->set("password",$password);
            $user->set("email",$email);
            try{
                $user->signUp();
            }catch(ParseException $exception){
                print_r($exception);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the following row:

```
$user->set("username",$user);
```

Your user object cannot be a username. Your username should be a string (it can be an email or some string that you receive by your users).
This line of code will not work even if you will set the $user into another field (and not as the username) the reason is because you are trying to save a relation to the same object that you are trying to create so the server telling you that it is an **infinite loop** and anyway there is no reason to do it.
so what you need to do is:

1. Use string in your **username** field
2. Use logged in user as a relationship of other objects